# log4j: Warn No appenders could be found 

Tags: log4j, liferay

I am receiving this warning which interrupts the running of my web application.

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (smslib).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I have the log4j JAR file in my library. I have deleted it and added it again ... this warning keeps showing up.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well log4j is clearly being found, otherwise it couldn't be warning you like this!

What's more likely to be missing is a log4j *configuration*. There are lots of ways you can do this in a web application - how are you trying?

Comment: I just tried running the application again and it ran just fine!! I think my netbeans has the problems!  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For small stand-alone programs and unit tests, I use `BasicConfigurator`.

To init:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

To cleanup:

```
BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();
```

If you're using JUnit, you should generally remember to place the cleanup code in your @After/tearDown(), since the configure() method adds a console appender if log4j had already been initialized.